# Convert UTC Time to IST time

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to convert UTC time to IST time.
But I got timein below format.
Time = 111524.000
plz let me know how to convert above format to IST format

I tried below code but it doesn't work for me

```
Dim str As String = "111524.000"
Dim formats As String() = New String() {"HH:mm:ss"}
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjuToUniversal)
Dim strTime As String = dt.ToShortTimeString()
```

I want time as 11:15:24

Comment: Well what date or time is 111524.000 meant to represent? It seems to me that this question has very little to do with time zones, and everything to do with working out what format that is...

Comment: how to convert this UTC format in local or IST time format like 11:15:24

Comment: Well what *date* is it meant to be on? A time of day could have a different offset from UTC depending on the date.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim str As String = "111524.000" 'UTC Time
    Dim formats As String = "HHmmss.fff"
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal Or Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
    Dim strTime As String = dt.ToString

    Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString & " " & dt.Kind.ToString)

    Dim IST As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")
    Dim ISTdt As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, IST)

    Debug.WriteLine(ISTdt.ToString & " " & ISTdt.Kind.ToString)
```